# How do I distort arc image on only top and bottom sides using imagick?

Tags: php, imagick

I want it to be like this:

[image]

But I am getting this:

[image]

```
<?php
$image = new imagick( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/op.jpg" );
$points = array(
    90,
);
$image->setimagebackgroundcolor("#fad888");
$image->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(\Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND);
$image->distortImage(\Imagick::DISTORTION_CYLINDER2PLANE, $points, true);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [wave filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.waveimage.php), not the distortion filter.

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick("googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
$image->setImageBackgroundColor("#fad888");
$image->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(\Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND);
$image->waveImage($image->getImageHeight() / -2, $image->getImageWidth() * 2);
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

You'll need to trim the image to remove the extra space added at the bottom. Output:

[image]